# Upon opening, the site goes quickly to left?

Tags: html, layout

When you are opening my website ["7daysdistribution"](http://7daysdistribution.com/blogg/), the layout goes quickly to the left and looks horrible. This happens for some seconds and it afterwards it looks right. Not all pages experience this only home (sometimes), brands, contact.  What can I do?

Comment: Can you reproduce this in JsFiddle? Do you have any idea what might be causing it?

Comment: You website also goes left for a blink in Chrome (stable).

Answer (score 2):

It flashes quickly on the left side in Opera as well, and I could see it happen on all pages actually.

Trying moving the *responsive-style.css* `<link>` further up in the source. Might be that it takes a moment to load, and until that style is loaded then the center alignment of `.container` won't take effect.

The effect will be more pronounced in IE8 because IE8 only downloads two files at a time, so it takes longer before it gets around to *responsive-style.css* since there are a lot of other files to download first.

Comment: Hi! @Supr I'm a newbie on programming but do you mean in functions.php to switch place in function.php? So the wp_register_style (responsive-style.css) is before base.css and layout css. And  the  wp_enqueue_style ('responsive') is before base and layout?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about Wordpress (?) programming so I don't know how to affect the position of the style-sheets. But what I mean is that responsive-style.css should be placed *before* the content in the generated HTML. Maybe you can place the `wp_register_style(...)` closer to the top? Or just add a plain `<link>`-tag for that style-sheet directly without using `wp_register_style`?